# Using org.slf4j.Marker with ActorLogging

Tags: scala, akka, slf4j, logback

I have the need to use log markers (org.slf4j.Marker) when my actors perform logging.
I am using logback as a logging library, and just as a general practice suggests all my actors are mixing in a LoggingActor trait which enables the logging functionality.

I guess since my actors don't use the slf4j facade, then I can not use the the markers when I perform logging.

Is there a way to be able doing something like: log.info(myMarker,"My logging message..") ??
Or maybe some other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The `ActorLogging` trait does not provide direct access to the SLF4J API but there is nothing stopping you from using it directly in your actors.

Just be careful with slf4j doing blocking io when you write to the log (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/logging.html#slf4j-directly-scala).

Comment: Hi. 
The thing is that I'm using a logback-logstash-encoder in order to send some strings into logstash. Those are pretty heavy logs, so I wouldn't like doing it synchronously, now I could use the AsyncAppender that slf4j provides  but  in my case I have to use a specific appender that is provided by the logback-logstash library.
So I guess the only possibility in my case is creating a logging actor of my own (which will use slf4j directly) or using Futures..?